# How do I shift specific elements of a tensor with torch.roll?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `x`, that looks like this:

```
x = tensor([  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
           [  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]
           [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

I'm trying to switch the first two and last two numbers of each tensor, like this:

```
x = tensor([  4,  5,  3,  1,  2],
           [  9, 10,  8,  6,  7],
           [ 14, 15, 13, 11, 12])
```

How could I do this with `torch.roll()`? How would I switch 3 instead of 1?

Comment: What do you mean by *switch 3 instead of 1*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that can be done with `torch.roll` alone... However, you can expect the desired result by using a temporary tensor and a pair assignment:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(1, 16).reshape(3,-1)
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

>>> tmp = x.clone()

# swap the two sets of columns
>>> x[:,:2], x[:,-2:] = tmp[:,-2:], tmp[:,:2]
```

Such that tensor `x` has been mutated as:

```
>>> x
tensor([[ 4,  5,  3,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10,  8,  6,  7],
        [14, 15, 13, 11, 12]])
```

---

You can pull off this operation with [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.roll.html) and some indexing:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(1, 21).reshape(4,-1)
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

>>> rolled = x.roll(-2,0)
tensor([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])

# overwrite columns [1,-1[ from rolled with those from x
>>> rolled[:, 1:-1] = x[:, 1:-1]
```

Such that at this end you get:

```
>>> rolled
tensor([[11,  2,  3,  4, 15],
        [16,  7,  8,  9, 20],
        [ 1, 12, 13, 14,  5],
        [ 6, 17, 18, 19, 10]])
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that notation. Could I use the same notation to do the same in the y-direction? This would mean that the numbers would be moving cross element. So the input should be:

tensor([ [1,2,3,4,5],
              [6,7,8,9,10],
              [11,12,13,14,15],
              [16,17,18,19,20]
])

And the output:   

tensor([ [11,2,3,4,15],
              [16,7,8,9,20],
              [1,12,13,14,5],
              [6,17,18,19,10]
])

Comment: @DarrelGulseth This actually would require `torch.roll` this time around. Please look at my edit above for a full walkthrough.